PfSense : i get "cannot connect to installer daemon" when the install begin
I want to install pfSense from my USB key, so I boot on it, I get the menu, it starts automatically on multi user mode, and then the "graphical" interface starts and I get a "cannot connect to installer daemon" message. And 2 buttons, "retry" or "exit".
Of course, if I retry, I still get "cannot connect to installer daemon".
I use an Asus Vivobook.
During the install of linux (ubuntu) the embedded ethernet card was not recognized, there is no linux driver for it, so I had to plug a USB Wifi adapter, and it was recognised during the ubuntu install. Maybe pfSense can't recognized it and I got this message because it can't find any network interfaces? I don't know.
Any clue?
Thanks
